# Verifying email sent via Oracle

Tags: oracle, email, plsql

Is there a query that I can use to show all emails I have sent via Oracle using the built-in procedure?

I want to see how many emails have been successfully sent and how many were not sent.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on which procedure you use.

- `UTL_MAIL`, `UTL_SMTP` or `UTL_TCP` - these packages don't do any logging, you need to log emails yourself
- `APEX_MAIL` - this package logs emails in `APEX_MAIL_LOG`

Comment: I use `UTL_SMTP`, how do you suggest that I do the logging by myself?

Comment: You insert a row into a table.